# Команда pip show не выводит ничего

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

При выполнении в консоли команда вида

```
pip show <имя пакета>
```

не выводится ничего. Абсолютно ничего... Например:

```
$ pip3 show tkinter
$ pip3 show -v PyQt5
$ pip show -v os
$ pip3 show -v os
```

Хотя пакеты tkinter и прочие установлены и работают. Пакет можно задавать ЛЮБОЙ. Флаг *-v* никакого влияния не оказывает.

И что это значит?

Comment: Что показывает ``pip list``?

Comment: У вас какая версия pip? У меня тоже не показывает инфу, только предупреждение о том, что версию pip можно обновить: `You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.`. `pip list` работает

Comment: У меня показывает информацию только о тех пакетах, которые перечислены в ``pip list``, т.е. установлены дополнительно, а не включены в дистрибутив языка.

Comment: *Что показывает pip list?* - список из 129 пакетов.

Comment: *У вас какая версия pip?* - Обе. Если запускаю pip2 - говорит про то, что нужно обновиться. Если pip3 - ничего не говорит.

Comment: *показывает информацию только о тех пакетах, которые перечислены в pip list* - похоже, Вы правы! Проверил на 5 пакетах из списка *pip list* - показал все. И это странно... А если мне нужна информация о предустановленном пакете?!

Comment: Можно как-то так: `python -c "import tkinter; help(tkinter)"`. Но это не метаинформация о пакете, а непосредственно документация.